# Laravel 5.4 Mix: How to use Bootstrap-sass (under the nodes_module) folder in my project?

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-mix

Newbie Laravel user here.

I have the following lines in app.scss file (created automatically by Laravel):

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600);
@import "variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

Question: How do I make use of Bootstrap in my project? I don't see it getting compiled or getting copied to my public/css folder. And in general, how do I pull in any packages in the nodes_module to my Laravel project using Mix. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Laravel Mix, Bootstrap is automatically imported in your `resources/assets/js/app.js` and `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js`.

Also with the last import, it is bringing all of bootstrap inside your CSS, so when you run `npm run watch` it will copy all of it and you'll be able to use it.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that Bootstrap got merge with my app.css. Stupid me! I was actually looking for a separate Bootstrap files. So that's where the "Mix" comes in. lol! Anyway, is it possible to configure Mix to output the files separately, including other packages I might use in the future? I just thought that it's more manageable that way.

Thanks for taking time to answer.

Comment: @gibi Yeah you just have to add the `.extract(['bootstrap', 'other']')` to your `webpack.mix.js`, see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#vendor-extraction